# error build android JB for pandaboard using linaro 13.4

Tags: android, build

I'm trying to build android JB for pandaboard using Linaro 13.4. During the build I'm getting the following error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/10cfded1-3e14-42c3-9b1b-
b03ecaf8e45a/pandaboard_jb/kernel/linaro/pandaboard/tools/perf' 
Makefile:438: *** No gnu/libc-version.h found, please install glibc-dev[el]/glibc-static. 
Stop. make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/10cfded1-3e14-42c3-9b1b-b03ecaf8e45a/pandaboard_jb/kernel/linaro/pandaboard/tools/perf' 
make: *** [android_kernel] Error 2.
```

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with building perf for Android JB..

Are you trying to build perf statically outside the android source?

Take a look at [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/)

It **looks** as if you're trying to independently build perf.
I suggest you clone the repository above and add it to your Android source's platform/external directory.

You will have to add external/linux-tools-perf to `platform/build/core/main.mk` as well